# J and L-systems

Tags: arrays, list, j, l-systems

I'm going to create a program that can generate strings from [L-system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) grammars.

Astrid Lindenmayer's original L-System for modelling the growth of algae is:

```
variables : A B  
constants : none  
axiom     : A  
rules     : (A → AB), (B → A)
```

which produces:

```
iteration | resulting model
        0 | A
        1 | AB
        2 | ABA
        3 | ABAAB
        4 | ABAABABA
        5 | ABAABABAABAAB
```

that is naively implemented by myself in J like this:

```
   algae =: 1&algae : (([: ; (('AB'"0)`('A'"0) @. ('AB' i. ]))&.>"0)^:[) "1 0 1
   (i.6) ([;algae)"1 0 1 'A'
┌─┬─────────────┐
│0│A            │
├─┼─────────────┤
│1│AB           │
├─┼─────────────┤
│2│ABA          │
├─┼─────────────┤
│3│ABAAB        │
├─┼─────────────┤
│4│ABAABABA     │
├─┼─────────────┤
│5│ABAABABAABAAB│
└─┴─────────────┘
```

Step-by-step illustration:

```
   ('AB' i. ]) 'ABAAB' NB. determine indices of productions for each variable
0 1 0 0 1
   'AB'"0`('A'"0)@.('AB' i. ])"0 'ABAAB' NB. apply corresponding productions 
AB
A 
AB
AB
A
   'AB'"0`('A'"0)@.('AB' i. ])&.>"0 'ABAAB' NB. the same &.> to avoid filling
┌──┬─┬──┬──┬─┐
│AB│A│AB│AB│A│
└──┴─┴──┴──┴─┘
   NB. finally ; and use ^: to iterate
```

By analogy, here is a result of the 4th iteration of [L-system that generates Thue–Morse sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence#L-system)

```
   4 (([: ; (0 1"0)`(1 0"0)@.(0 1 i. ])&.>"0)^:[) 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
```

That is the best that I can do so far. I believe that boxing-unboxing method is insufficient here. This is the first time I've missed linked-lists in J - it's much harder to code grammars without them.

What I'm really thinking about is:
a) constructing a list of gerunds of those functions that build final string (in my examples those functions are constants like `'AB'"0` but in case of tree modeling functions are turtle graphics commands) and evoking (`` `:6 ``) it,
or something that I am able to code:
b) constructing a string of legal J sentence that build final string and doing (`".`) it.
But I'm not sure if these programs are efficient.

- Can you show me a better approach please?

Any hints as well as comments about *a)* and *b)* are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will pad the rectangular array with spaces:

```
   L=: rplc&('A';'AB';'B';'A')
   L^:(<6) 'A'
A            
AB           
ABA          
ABAAB        
ABAABABA     
ABAABABAABAAB
```

Or if you don't want padding:

```
   L&.>^:(<6) <'A'
┌─┬──┬───┬─────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│A│AB│ABA│ABAAB│ABAABABA│ABAABABAABAAB│
└─┴──┴───┴─────┴────────┴─────────────┘
```

Obviously you'll want to inspect `rplc` / `stringreplace` to see what is happening under the covers.

Comment: Unless performance is an issue, `rplc` is the most straightforward approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use complex values in the left argument of `#` to expand an array without boxing.

For this particular L-system, I'd probably skip the gerunds and use a temporary substitution:

```
to  =: 2 : 'n (I.m=y) } y'        NB. replace n with m in y
ins =: 2 : '(1 j. m=y) #!.n y'    NB. insert n after each m in y
L =:  [: 'c'to'A' [: 'A'ins'B' [: 'B'to'c' ]
```

Then:

```
    L^:(<6) 'A'
A
AB
ABA
ABAAB
ABAABABA
ABAABABAABAAB
```

Here's a more general approach that simplifies the code by using numbers and a gerund composed of constant functions:

```
   'x'-.~"1 'xAB'{~([:,(0:`(1:,2:)`1:)@.]"0)^:(<6) 1
A
AB
ABA
ABAAB
ABAABABA
ABAABABAABAAB
```

The AB are filled in at the end for display. There's no boxing here because I use 0 as a null value. These get scattered around quite a bit but the `-.~"1` removes them. It does pad all the resulting strings with nulls on the right. If you don't want that, you can use `<@-.~"1` to box the results instead:

```
   'x'<@-.~"1 'xAB'{~([:,(0:`(1:,2:)`1:)@.]"0)^:(<6) 1
┌─┬──┬───┬─────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│A│AB│ABA│ABAAB│ABAABABA│ABAABABAABAAB│
└─┴──┴───┴─────┴────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Than you, your answer is useful for me, however the answer of Tikkanz appeared to be more efficient both in time and space. And thanks for pointing the `^:(<n)` construct - I didn't know it.